# AWS Redshift: How often are STL tables purged

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Does anyone know how often are system tables in Redshift purged? Is Redshift doing it internally?

I can't find anything in the official Redshift guide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Found it after all:** 
To manage disk space, the STL log tables only retain approximately two to five days of log history, depending on log usage and available disk space. If you want to retain the log data, you will need to periodically copy it to other tables or unload it to Amazon S3.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_intro_STL_tables.html